# jQuery HtmlBox limit number of words/chars entered

Tags: jquery, count, cpu-word, limit

I have HtmlBox 4.0.3 from Remiya on a Joomla website and would like to know how (if possible) I would be able to limit the amount of chars/words entered into the textarea of HtmlBox.

I've already managed to limit the chars/words on a plain html textarea but HtmlBox is written completely in jQuery and I don't even know where to start.

Any help much appreciated,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really basic example of what you could do:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxLength = 150; // max number of allowed characters
  $('#yourHtmlBoxId').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, maxLength));
    $('#charCount').text(maxLength - $(this).val().length);
  });
  $('#yourHtmlBoxId').trigger('keyup');
});
```

Obviously you need to replace `#yourHtmlBoxId` and `#charCount` with the relevant selectors.

Some example markup:

```
<textarea id="yourHtmlBoxId"></textarea>
<p><span id="charCount"></span> remaining</p>
```

[Here's a fiddle for you to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/dg8Nk/1/)

Just bear in mind that this is by no means bullet proof, it works on the `keyup` event, so for example if somebody copy/pasted into the textarea via mouse buttons the jQuery would never be triggered. This should point you in the right direction though.

Comment: Thank-you deifwud, I had to verify via php before sending to the database so I worked it into my php.